# Average with where condition in an array in mongo across all collections

Tags: arrays, mongodb, average

I need to find the average age for ward 2 in mongo document.

```
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57113238bde91693e9ff69e7"),
            "docname" : "Arthur Hovsepyan",
            "job_desc" : "Hepatologist",
            "sex" : "male",
            "jobtype" : "fulltime",
            "office" : "room 448",
            "email" : "arturchik@hotmail.com",
            "phone_number" : 862124343,
            "address" : "68 Peterburg street,waterford",
            "hours" : 12,
            "patients" : [
                    {
                            "name" : "Jenny Power",
                            "ward_no" : 1,
                            "sex" : "female",
                            "termdays" : 2,
                            "illness_type" : "minor",
                            "age" : 22,
                            "phone_number" : 877285221,
                            "address" : "63 Johnston street ,Waterford"
                    },
                    {
                            "name" : "Marie Peters",
                            "ward_no" : 2,
                            "sex" : "female",
                            "termdays" : 0,
                            "illness_type" : "minor",
                            "age" : 21,
                            "phone_number" : 862145992,
                            "address" : "99 Grange,Waterford"
                    },
                    {
                            "name" : "Philip John",
                            "ward_no" : 2,
                            "sex" : "male",
                            "termdays" : 10,
                            "illness_type" : "serious",
                            "age" : 31,
                            "phone_number" : 861125981,
                            "address" : "12 Monvoy Bridge,Waterford"
                    },
                    {
                            "name" : "Marta Peters",
                            "ward_no" : 3,
                            "sex" : "female",
                            "termd7ays" : 0,
                            "illness_type" : "minor",
                            "age" : 31,
                            "phone_number" : 862125981,
                            "address" : "100 Grange Manor,Waterford"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

I need to find the average age in ward number 2.I'm trying to compute an average aggregation operation on eah values of an array for each documents in my collection where ward no =2.

Answer (score 0):

We need to apply [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator to filter only `ward_no = 2` and with [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) returns `age array` filtered from prevous step and [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/index.html) operator returns expected result.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      avg: {
        $avg: {
          $let: {
            vars: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$patients",
                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.ward_no", 2 ] }
                }
              }
            },
            in: "$$input.age"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RQ8Q6PWx3Lo) | [All documents average age](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aaSuMPR1UVx)

**Note:** Replace `$addFields` to `$project` if you want return only average result.

Comment: What to do if need to do across all documents average age for ward number 2 patients. ?

Comment: @Kulbirsingh I've updated my answer, please take a look a link "All documents average age"